# Django templates url - differentiate between same url names

Tags: django, django-templates

in my application I've got a view called download_document which works fine using **{% url 'download_document' some_id %}** .

Installing a 3rd party app into the virtual environment cause trouble because this app has also the download_document view (also accepting one ID parameter) with the same urlname.

If I'd like to use both with this name, can I somehow make the difference between them? For instance using both cases in the same template file?

Python: 2.7
Django: 1.11.16
Debian .

---

Update #1:

my app is called **infk** . I tried already using

```
{% url 'infk:download_document' document.id %}
```

, but in this case I got a 500 with: u'infk' is not a registered namespace.

I also tried adding namespace to the top urls.py file:

```
#original
url(r'^infk/', include('infk.urls')),
#modified
url(r'^infk/', include('infk.urls', namespace="infk")),
```

but in this case i got back a different 500: Reverse for 'infk' not found. 'infk' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

To work the second one I'd need to change at least all reverse methods from ** reverse('infk'...) to reverse('infk:infk'...) which I don't really want.

So if I don't add namespace, is there any way to call my download_document function? (By default it calls the 3rd party app's download_document view .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long post ahead, so deep breath...

> So if I don't add namespace, is there any way to call my download_document function? (By default it calls the 3rd party app's download_document view .

That depends on what you're trying to do. If you *always* want your download_document function to be called throughout your entire website (even on the pages provided by the 3rd-party-app), you can just move infk to the end of your `urlpatterns` in `main_app/urls`. That would look something like this:

```
main_app/urls.py
================================================================================
from django.conf.urls import include, url

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^3rd-party-app/', include('3rd-party-app.urls')),
    url(r'^infk/', include('infk.urls')),
]
```

Otherwise, if you're trying to get your download_document in specific instances without namespaces, it's not particularly easily. You could create a custom tag that always produces the url for your download_document function, but that's a lot of extra work, and if you run into another name conflict, you'd have to do it again and again, and that's barely a step above hard-coding the url in the first place. Plus, if you're planning to deploy infk as a third party app, you'll probably want to use a namespace to help other people avoid the same problem you're having.

## Explanation

According to the docs at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns:

> If you call your URL pattern *comment* and another application does the same thing, the URL that reverse() finds depends on whichever pattern is last in your project’s urlpatterns list.

So if you change the order of your included urls in your main_app/urls.py file such that infk is after the 3rd-party app, you should get the infk download_document. However, this means that you'll ALWAYS get the infk download_document, which may break some of the functionality in your 3rd-party app.

## Examples

### Django 1.x

Source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/urls/#reversing-namespaced-urls

Your modified `url(r'^infk/', include('infk.urls', namespace="infk"))` has created an instance namespace, which might make sense if you are using multiple instances of infk throughout your app. If you aren't (or you're planning on deploying infk as a third-party app itself) you probably don't need that. Either way, I'd recommend you set the application namespace.

```
main_app/urls.py
================================================================================
from django.conf.urls import include, url

urlpatterns = [

    # These are both instance namespaces. Note that although the same urls 
    # are being included from infk.urls for both, the final route will be 
    # different.
    url(r'^infk-instance1/', include('infk.urls', namespace='infk-instance1')),
    url(r'^infk-instance2/', include('infk.urls', namespace='infk-instance2')),

    # The 3rd-party app your url and reverse functions are colliding with.
    url(r'^3rd-party-app/', include('3rd-party-app.urls')),
]
```

```
infk/urls.py
================================================================================
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

# This is the application namespace. I recommend setting this regardless of 
# whether you use instance namespaces.
app_name = 'infk'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.download_document(), name='download_document'),
]
```

#### Instance Namespaces

Instance namespaces would be called like this:

```
infk/foo_template.html
================================================================================
...
  <!-- In this case, {% url 'infk-instance1:download_document' document.id %}
  will return /infk-instance1/<document.id>-->

  <a href="{% url 'infk-instance1:download_document' document.id %}">Download Document</a>
...
```

```
ingk/foo_template.html
================================================================================
...
  <!-- In this case, {% url 'infk-instance2:download_document' document.id %}
  will return /infk-instance2/<document.id>-->

  <a href="{% url 'infk-instance2:download_document' document.id %}">Download Document</a>
...
```

You should still be able to get the 3rd-party download_document url, if you need it. Note that in order for this to work, 3rd-party-app.urls must be included AFTER infk.urls.

```
ingk/foo_template.html
================================================================================
...
  <!-- In this case, {% url 'download_document' document.id %}
  will return /3rd-party-app/<document.id>-->

  <a href="{% url 'download_document' document.id %}">Download Document</a>
...
```

#### Application Namespaces

The behavior of application namespaces depends on whether there are instance namespaces defined for the application or not, and whether the view called defines a current_app. If you use the above example where both application and instance namespaces are defined, then using an application namespace in your `{% url %}` tag may return inconsistent results. (See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/urls/#reversing-namespaced-urls for more information)

For ease of explanation, I'm going to assume you are not using multiple instances of the infk app. Your main_app/urls.py might then look like:

```
main_app/urls.py
================================================================================
from django.conf.urls import include, url

urlpatterns = [
    # No instance namespaces
    url(r'^infk/', include('infk.urls')),
    url(r'^3rd-party-app/', include('3rd-party-app.urls')),
]
```

Application namespaces are called like this:

```
infk/foo_template.html
================================================================================
...
  <!-- In this case, {% url 'infk:download_document' document.id %}
  will return /infk/<document.id>-->

  <a href="{% url 'infk:download_document' document.id %}">Download Document</a>
...
```

And, assuming that 3rd-party app is installed AFTER infk, your 3rd-party app's download_document can still be called like:

```
ingk/foo_template.html
================================================================================
...
  <!-- In this case, {% url 'download_document' document.id %}
  will return /3rd-party-app/<document.id>-->

  <a href="{% url 'download_document' document.id %}">Download Document</a>
...
```

### Django >=2.x

Source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#term-application-namespace

The resolver works essentially the same as described above; however, instead of using `url()` in your urls.py files, use `path()` or `re_path()`.

Comment: Thanks for the brief explanation.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to avoid `url` name conflicts. All you have to do is to add their respective namespaces before the `url` name. As per [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#url), all you need is the following:

```
{% url 'myapp:view-name' %}
```

By using the [namespaced URL resolution strategy](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/urls/#topics-http-reversing-url-namespaces).

Comment: I updated the original question under Update #1 with your solution, but I can't really change all (few hundreds) url-type occurences in the project. I think I'd need to change all template->url tags and all reverse lines..

Comment: @user2194805 I don't see another way to do this, so I think that your IDE or Editor could do that really easy to change all hundreds of occurrences.

Comment: Well, I found another tricky workaround, however, it's strange that I can't tell in the url template tag exactly which one I'd like to use. It can happen quite easily that 2 3rd party apps using the same viewname, and it'd be very useful imho to be able to distinguish between them.